# Is bcrypt really better at mitigating GPU attacks than other key derivation algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

bcrypt was designed over 10 years ago.

According to opinionated internet voices, bcrypt is better than alternatives like PBKDF2 because of its GPGPU attack mitigation features (high memory, mutating tables) even though both algorithms have a modifiable work factor which slows down brute-forcing attempts.

I've read that bcrypt really only takes 4k of mutable memory and that for modern GPUs or FPGAs, it's no better than alternatives.

How true is this? Does bcrypt even have an advantage versus these sorts of attacks anymore?

Comment: There is in fact yet another KDF, scrypt, which is designed with these things in mind. It is difficult to run on a GPU or FPGA due to memory requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**bcrypt is comparatively stronger than PBKDF2**

1. Even though modern GPUs and FPGAs may have enough memory to handle bcrypt, the higher memory requirement still slows them down in comparison to the SHA hash family (the basis of most PBKDF2 implementations).
2. Blowfish is a very hard algorithm to vectorize, unlike the SHA family. Vectorizing SHA is very GPU-friendly and allows a lot more parallelism.

**It might not matter though**

bcrypt has a linear advantage over PBKDF2, at best. That is if the enemy can crack a PBKDF2 system in X time, they could crack a bcrypt system in n*X time, for some constant n>1. And n is probably not big enough to make a game-changing difference.

The way I look at it is, if my password is weak enough to be broken in any reasonable amount of time, then multiplying that amount of time by n (by changing algorithms) is not going to change things that much.

Answer (score 1):

The more advanced the encryption the more advanced the technology becomes to beat it.

bcrypt is good because it allows you to scale the size making it harder for a traditional computer attack. However, if you are really worried about more sophisticated attacks research how to prevent those type of attacks specifically. You will probably have to use a combination of security measures depending on the level of sophistication the attack has.

But for the majority of sites just looking to protect passwords of their users bcrypt is a pretty darn good option.